# Copy certain value to varying position in defined worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am working on a macro that takes the value in H2 in the 3rd sheet of the workbook and copies it to the column behind the last used column in row 5 in the row that contains the word "page" in column A in a worksheet called "Overview", but only if the value in H2 is not 0. After that, i need to add a string in row 4 in the same column that the value was posted to. Can somebody help me get my code to work? I specifically have issues with copying the value. THis is what i have so far:

```
'
' example Macro
'

'
   
   
Dim cRange As Range
Dim valuessendmemore As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
    
    'set worksheets
With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets(3)
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")
End With
    


LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(5, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set cRange = wsSource.Range("H2")


    For Each Cell In cRange
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        Cell.Value.Copy
          
        'Set the value you want to search
        strSearch = "*Page*"
        
        'Set the column you want to seach
        ColumnNo = 1
        
        'Create a with statement to point Sheet1.
        With wsDestination
            
            'Search for strSearch in column number ColumnNo
            Set rngFound = .Columns(ColumnNo).Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                  
                'Paste row
                wsDestination.Range(LastColumn1 & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                'Delete row
       
       
            End If
         
        End With
   
    End If
    
    Next Cell
   
   
   
    
   
  

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem no doubt lies in this statement `Range(LastColumn1 & rngFound.Row)`.  Say your `LastColumn1` evaluated to 25 and `rngFound.Row` evaluated to 1000.  Now your statement says `Range(251000)` which doesn't exist.  The proper rewrite would be:

`wsDestination.Cells(rngFound.Row, LastColumn1)...`